# required by a bound in `Methods::merge`

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc

i gonna add custom rpc in substrate , but every time i run this command : `cargo check` , it show me this error :

```rs
        error[E0277]: the trait bound `Methods: From<jsonrpsee_core::server::rpc_module::RpcModule<TemplatePallet<C, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>>>` is not satisfied
       --> node/src/rpc.rs:53:15
        |
    53  |     module.merge(TemplatePallet::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;
        |            ----- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<jsonrpsee_core::server::rpc_module::RpcModule<TemplatePallet<C, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>>>` is not implemented for `Methods`
        |            |
        |            required by a bound introduced by this call
        |
        = help: the trait `From<RpcModule<Context>>` is implemented for `Methods`
        = note: required for `jsonrpsee_core::server::rpc_module::RpcModule<TemplatePallet<C, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>>` to implement `Into<Methods>`
    note: required by a bound in `Methods::merge`
       --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/jsonrpsee-core-0.16.2/src/server/rpc_module.rs:311:38
        |
    311 |     pub fn merge(&mut self, other: impl Into<Methods>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Methods::merge`
    
    For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
    error: could not compile `node-template` due to previous error


    [Repository][1]
```

these are my codes : ‍‍‍

`pallets/template/src/rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs`

````rs
    #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
    
    // Here we declare the runtime API. It is implemented it the `impl` block in
    // runtime file (the `runtime-api/src/lib.rs`)
    sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
        pub trait TemplateApi {
            fn get_value() -> u32;
        }
    }

‍‍`pallets/template/src/rpc`

        pub use pallet_template_runtime_api::TemplateApi as TemplateRuntimeApi;
    use jsonrpsee::{
        core::{Error as JsonRpseeError, RpcResult},
        proc_macros::rpc,
        types::error::{CallError, ErrorObject},
    };
    use sp_api::ProvideRuntimeApi;
    use sp_blockchain::HeaderBackend;
    use sp_runtime::{generic::BlockId, traits::Block as BlockT};
    use std::sync::Arc;
    
    #[rpc(client, server)]
    pub trait TemplateApi<BlockHash> {
        #[method(name = "template_getValue")]
        fn get_value(&self, at: Option<BlockHash>) -> RpcResult<u32>;
    }
    
    /// A struct that implements the `TemplateApi`.
    pub struct TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
        // If you have more generics, no need to TemplatePallet<C, M, N, P, ...>
        // just use a tuple like TemplatePallet<C, (M, N, P, ...)>
        client: Arc<C>,
        _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<Block>,
    }
    
    impl<C, Block> TemplatePallet<C, Block> {
        /// Create new `TemplatePallet` instance with the given reference to the client.
        pub fn new(client: Arc<C>) -> Self {
            Self { client, _marker: Default::default() }
        }
    }
    
    impl<C, Block> TemplateApiServer<<Block as BlockT>::Hash> for TemplatePallet<C, Block>
    where
        Block: BlockT,
        C: Send + Sync + 'static + ProvideRuntimeApi<Block> + HeaderBackend<Block>,
        C::Api: TemplateRuntimeApi<Block>,
    {
        fn get_value(&self, at: Option<<Block as BlockT>::Hash>) -> RpcResult<u32> {
            let api = self.client.runtime_api();
            let at = BlockId::hash(at.unwrap_or_else(||self.client.info().best_hash));
    
            api.get_value(&at).map_err(runtime_error_into_rpc_err)
        }
    }
    
    const RUNTIME_ERROR: i32 = 1;
    
    /// Converts a runtime trap into an RPC error.
    fn runtime_error_into_rpc_err(err: impl std::fmt::Debug) -> JsonRpseeError {
        CallError::Custom(ErrorObject::owned(
            RUNTIME_ERROR,
            "Runtime error",
            Some(format!("{:?}

    ", err)),
        ))
        .into()
    }
`‍‍‍‍``

‍‍`runtime/src/lib.rs`

```rs
    ‍‍impl pallet_template_runtime_api::TemplateApi<Block> for Runtime {
        fn get_value() -> u32 {
            TemplateModule::get_value().unwrap_or(0)
        }
    }
````

`node/rpc.rs`

```rs
    /// Instantiate all full RPC extensions.
    pub fn create_full<C, P>(
        deps: FullDeps<C, P>,
    ) -> Result<RpcModule<()>, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>
    where
        C: ProvideRuntimeApi<Block>,
        C: HeaderBackend<Block> + HeaderMetadata<Block, Error = BlockChainError> + 'static,
        C: Send + Sync + 'static,
        C::Api: substrate_frame_rpc_system::AccountNonceApi<Block, AccountId, Index>,
        C::Api: pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::TransactionPaymentRuntimeApi<Block, Balance>,
        C::Api: pallet_template_rpc::TemplateRuntimeApi<Block>,
        C::Api: BlockBuilder<Block>,
        P: TransactionPool + 'static,
    {
        use pallet_transaction_payment_rpc::{TransactionPayment, TransactionPaymentApiServer};
        use substrate_frame_rpc_system::{System, SystemApiServer};
        use pallet_template_rpc::{TemplatePallet, TemplateApiServer};
    
        let mut module = RpcModule::new(());
        let FullDeps { client, pool, deny_unsafe } = deps;
    
        module.merge(System::new(client.clone(), pool.clone(), deny_unsafe).into_rpc())?;
        module.merge(TransactionPayment::new(client.clone()).into_rpc())?;
        module.merge(TemplatePallet::new(client).into_rpc())?;
    
        // Extend this RPC with a custom API by using the following syntax.
        // `YourRpcStruct` should have a reference to a client, which is needed
        // to call into the runtime.
        // `module.merge(YourRpcTrait::into_rpc(YourRpcStruct::new(ReferenceToClient, ...)))?;`
    
        Ok(module)
    }
```

Comment: It's a little bit hard to diagnose this long context. If there is a code link that would be better.

Comment: Coming back to this as I am facing same issue. Any progress @Mr Coder?

Comment: It works for me to update jsonrpsee to any version that above 0.16.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make it compile by upgrading `jsonrpsee` package from version `0.15.1` to version `0.16.2`. I hope this helps you.

Comment: It is really works!